# Android Button setBackground() causes highlight effect to go away

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to programmatically add a background resource to a button but as soon as I do that, the highlight effect of when the button is clicked goes away. How do I restore the highlight effect while still using the background?

button_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@layout/avail_button_solid" />        
  <item android:drawable="@layout/avail_button_shape" />
</layer-list>
```

avail_button_solid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ababab" />   
</shape>
```

avail_button_shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" /> 
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff000000" />  
</shape>
```

Java code:

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.button_layout);
```

The code sets the background but takes away the highlighting effect.

Comment: You should use `<selector />`

Comment: Take a look at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2fd686/android-buttons-background2/ . You need to use `<selector>`

Comment: This link helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons (and many other Android widgets) use a `<selector>` drawable (the analog in the SDK is a `StateListDrawable`). This is actually a Drawable container that maps different drawables to different states: pressed, focused, disabled, normal, etc. You should make one of these yourself if you want to replace the button background.

Read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html